# Jsoup exception 404

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to fetch the following url http://meteo.bg/en/ and here is my command

```
String url = "http://meteo.bg/en/";
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
               // here i am getting data
            }
        }
        return data;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        return null;
    }
```

However it throws an exception 404. When i use the Jsoup demo page at https://try.jsoup.org/, the above url is fetched successfully. Please tell me what i am doing wrong, or the site has some kind of protection?

Comment: Try `https://meteo.bg/en/`. The Web server redirects `http` to `https`, as you can tell by visiting http://meteo.bg/en/ in your favorite Web browser.

Comment: I have tried this before posting the question, same result 404 do you have another idea?

Comment: org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:762); org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:707); org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:297); org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:286)